# Compare 2 dates with diff datatypes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a *temp_table* where I have to update status to *Invalid* date if *Create_date* is a future date.
Following is the update statement I am using :

```
Set dateformat dmy
UPDATE [Temp_table] 
SET [Status]= 'InvalidCreateDate-Rejected' 
WHERE CAST(Create_date AS DATETIME) >=getdate() and isdate(create_date)=1
```

But whenever I execute it I get error message as:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a varchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The
>   statement has been terminated.

I tried converting *Getdate* and *Create_date* in diff formats and then compared still the same issue.

Sample Create_Dates: 
05/15/1800
04/06/2011
23/04/2015
13/08/2016
02/21/2017
15/06/2017

Any solution on this?

Comment: What's an example of `Create_date`? I suspect you'll need to cast as `datetime2`. Also, this logic is flawed. As soon as you run this, it's wrong because time has elapsed. You should check the `Status` when you query the data so it's up-to-date. Otherwise, you'd have to update the column every before each query to ensure it's "accurate" and up-to-date.

Comment: It's not exactly pretty but perhaps just alter `CAST(Create_date AS DATETIME)` to be `CAST(CASE WHEN ISDATE(Create_date) = 1 THEN Create_Date END AS DATETIME)`. This would work because you're filtering out the ones that don't equal 1 in the other predicate and you avoid the issue of the order of predicate evaluation altogether.

Comment: What is the actual format of the dates in Create_date column in your database?  You cannot simply CAST American dates to British format for example.... You need CONVERT

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample of the data in the Create_date column...

Comment: Create_date has a varchar datatype.. It might contain dates with different different formats like dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy etc.. that's why I am filtering create_date with isdate() function

Comment: You are not filtering anything LOL, you are simply using another clause in your WHERE statement.... Perhaps use a subquery first using IsDate - then ONLY pass those results to your CAST

Comment: Test this in a SELECT statement first, then move on to your UPDATE

Comment: What I mean is - ALL your records are flowing through 'CAST(Create_date AS DATETIME) >=getdate()' aswell as IsDate...  You only want to deal with the records that pass IsDate

Comment: Yeah you are in for a world of HURT with that data....I suggest you split up your records into dmy mdy formats, and process separately...You can do it in one query but its going to be painful, use a few queries :)

Comment: Treat your problems separately... You have a few problems...DMY format vs MDY format - then deal with > getdate() afterwards

Comment: Got it .. My bad.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your cast of create_date is coming across an invalid date and causing the error. the is_date function is a good idea, but it isn't going to prevent the cast from hitting an error earlier.

```
Set dateformat dmy
UPDATE [Temp_table] 
SET [Status]= 'InvalidCreateDate-Rejected' 
WHERE CAST(case when  isdate(create_date)=1 then Create_date else null AS DATETIME) >=getdate()
```

You can use a date purposefully in the past instead of the null if the null causes issues, but casting a null to date and comparing it to a date should result in a false and have it removed from results

Comment: This is still a terrible idea to do and i'd stress this to the OP

Comment: @scsimon - depends on the data Priyanka is working with, but you are right with your comments.   Priyanka - ensure you've consider what scsimon is saying here.

Comment: @scsimon ..terrible? Didn't get you..
here Its mandatory for me to use ISDATE  otherwise it considers dates of other formats also.. which throws error

Comment: Read my original comment under your post @Priyanka

Answer (score 0):

However, you could use `case` expression which could handle your different date formats

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, Create_Dates,
                         CASE
                             WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Create_Dates, 4, 2) AS INT) > 12
                             THEN 101
                             ELSE 103
                         END);
```

Result :-

```
1800-05-15 00:00:00.000
2011-06-04 00:00:00.000
2015-04-23 00:00:00.000
2016-08-13 00:00:00.000
2017-02-21 00:00:00.000
2017-06-15 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: @Priyanka the above is for only the dates which u have provided in `Q`